# Regex match trailing slash except pattern

Tags: regex

I'm looking for strings that end with `/` but not when the string is equal to `/[a-z]{2}/` (with the 2 slashes in the pattern)

To exclude the unwanted string I would use :

```
(?!/[a-z]{2}/)
```

For strings ending in a slash I'd use :

```
.*/$
```

However, my limited knowledge with regular expression doesn't allow me to combine the two patterns. How would I do this ?

This would match :

```
/en/contact/
```

This wouldn't :

```
/en/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex should work for you:

```
^(?!\/[a-z]{2}\/).*\/$
```

You could check it ***[here](http://regex101.com/r/fJ8oB6)***.

*Update for your added requirement:*

```
^(?!^\/[a-z]{2}\/$).*\/$
```

**[The demo.](http://regex101.com/r/nG4wC1)**

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work:

```
^(?!.*?\/[a-z]{2}\/$).*?\/$
```

[Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/lJ1sW2)